# SQLite.Interop.dll not found even though it is where it should be

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll

When I create a console application (.NET Core) that works with a SQLite database, I reference System.Data.SQLite.Core v1.0.109.0 package, and the app runs fine. In the bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1 directory there are x86, x64 and a couple of other subfolders, each of which contains an SQLite.Interop.dll. But when I do the same in a Xamarin.Forms app (I made sure to install the package into all projects in the solution) this folder structure is there in the bin/x86/debug directory of the UWP application, but this time SQLite.Interop.dll cannot be found.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

**Possibility 1:**

You said you made sure to install the packages but have you tried to *restore* the packages?

`$ dotnet restore myXamarin.Forms.App.sln`

**Possibility 2:**

You mentioned both x86 and x64 architecture in the first (working) app but you've only mentioned x86 architecture in the second.  It's worth taking the small amount of time to inspect your build targets.